# What is a secure way to create a random number in Typescript?

Tags: random

I want to create a function that returns a random number in a given range, what is a secure way of doing that?

Comment: Secure against what? Is the number used by something important or just generate something generally unpredictable?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you can access javascript's [web crypto api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API) through typescript, then you may want to consider using the web crypto api's [Crypto.getRandomValues()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues) method to generate cryptographically secure random values.